# get body from axios POST Request with Slim Framework

Tags: reactjs, axios, slim

hi Guys im having trouble with get body form value in slim framework 3.

what im try for now is using axios in my react.js front end

this is the slim3 route file :
task.php

```
    <?php
    use Slim\Http\Request;
    use Slim\Http\Response;
    use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

    $app->post('/task/add', function(Request $request,Response $response){

       // parse body
       $parsedBody = $request->getParsedBody();

       // data for insert
       $data = [
        ":TASK_STATUS" => 1,
        ":IDUSRN" => 1,
        ":TASK_FOR" => 16,
        ":TASK_DATE_START" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ":TASK_DATE_END" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ":TASK_SUBJECT" => $parsedBody['task_subject'],
        ":TASK_DETAIL" => $parsedBody['task_detail']
       ];


$sql = "INSERT INTO task (TASK_STATUS,IDUSRN,TASK_FOR,TASK_DATE_START,TASK_DATE_END,TASK_SUBJECT,TASK_DETAIL
        ) VALUES (:TASK_STATUS,:IDUSRN,:TASK_FOR,:TASK_DATE_START,:TASK_DATE_END,:TASK_SUBJECT,:TASK_DETAIL)";

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        try{
            $stmt->execute($data);
            return $response->withStatus(200)->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")->withJson(["status"=>"success","message"=>"Task successfully added !"]);

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            return $response->withStatus(401)->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")->withJson(["status"=>"Gagal","message"=>"Data tidak bisa terinput !"]);
        }
    });
```

i can see the data is inserted succesfully. but im received task subject & task detail as null

this is the react.js post request handler :

```
saveTask(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const state = this.state;
        this.setState({
            addTask_status:false
        });

        const body = {                         
            task_subject: state.task_subject.value,
            task_detail: state.task_detail.value
        };

        axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/task/add',
          headers:{
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body
        }).then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((err)=>console.log(err));
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: First, you need to make sure that `state.task_subject.value` and `state.task_detail.value` does have defined values and those values are actually sent to backend application.

Comment: Hi yes i have those initial value set and loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to pass `body` in `data`

```
axios({ 
    method: 'post', 
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/task/add',
    headers:{
       "Content-Type": "application/json" 
    }, 
    data: body 
}).then(function(response) { 
    console.log(response);
});
```

See 
[Axios README.md](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/README.md)